# Proving that a product of matrices invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, beamforming, eigendecomposition

Given $R_x$ a Positive Definite (PD) covariance matrix of size $M\times M$ and $C$ a full rank $M \times N$ matrix, I want to prove that $C^* R_x^{-1} C$ is invertible to derive the Linearly Constrained Minimum Variance Beamforming.

My ideas so far:

1. Since $R_x$ commutes with its adjoint, it can be written using the eigendecomposition $R_x =  U \Lambda U^*$
2. $R_x$ is PD, $R_x^{-1}$ is also PD since $\lambda_i > 0 \Longrightarrow \lambda_i^{-1} > 0$
3. Matrix $U$ defines an orthonormal basis and $C$ is full rank. Can view $U^* C$ as a projection onto this basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer Cedron! Taking your same assumption $N \leq M$, and by definition of PD, $x^* R_x^{-1} x > 0\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^M \setminus \{0\}$ and since $C$ is full rank $\dim (\mathcal{R}(C)) = \min(M,N)= N$. By the rank-nulity theorem, $\dim (\mathcal{R}(C)) + \dim(\mathcal{N}(A))=N$, so we have that the null-space is trivial. This means the projection $\tilde{x} := C y \neq 0\quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^N \setminus \{0\}$. Hence
\begin{align}
\tilde{x} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow y = 0 \tag{1}
\end{align}
Now we can see that $\tilde{x}^* R_x^{-1} \tilde{x} > 0\quad \forall \tilde{x} \neq 0$ following from PD of $R_x^{-1}$ so using the latter and (1),
\begin{align}
\tilde{x}^* R_x^{-1} \tilde{x} := y^* C^* R_x^{-1} C y > 0\quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^N \setminus \{0\} \tag{2}
\end{align}
and thus $C^* R_x^{-1} C$ is PD and hence invertible.

Comment: $x$ is a (complex valued in general) vector, right ? so the product $x R_x^{-1} x$ does not define anything. I think you meant $x^H R_x^{-1} x$ ?

Comment: You're welcome, see my followup.

Comment: I've added an update, check it out.

Comment: If $N \ge M$ then $min(M,N) = M$.  Why did you change that?

Comment: Of course your assumption was $N \leq M$ so I just forgot to change this part (it was a mere typo)

Answer (score 2):

First, this question is probably better for MATH.SE, but I'll give it a shot.

It's been a long long time since I did this stuff.

If $N > M$:

1) $C^*$ has rank M.

2) $R_x^{-1}$ has rank M. (or it wouldn't exist as an inverse)

3) Therefore  $C^*R_x^{-1}$ has rank M, since $R_x^{-1}$ is a full rank square matrix.

4) $C$ has rank M

5) $C^*R_x^{-1}C$ has rank less than or equal to M and is NxN.

6) $C^*R_x^{-1}C$ is a not a full rank square matrix and is thus not invertible.

If $N \le M$:

1) $C^*$ has rank N.

2) $R_x^{-1}$ has rank M. (or it wouldn't exist as an inverse)

3) Therefore  $C^*R_x^{-1}$ has rank N.

4) $C$ has rank N

5) $C^*R_x^{-1}C$ has rank less than or equal to N and is NxN.

6) $C^*R_x^{-1}C$ could be full rank square matrix and is thus could be invertible.

At this point, I am not sure what is required for $C^*R_x^{-1}C$ to have rank N.  I have narrowed the results, but not fully answered your question.

Gosh, I hope I have this right.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524444/connection-between-rank-and-positive-definiteness

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272049/rank-of-matrix-ab-when-a-and-b-have-full-rank

---

Starting with another disclaimer:  Ordinarily I don't answer questions here unless I am fairly rock solid in my understanding of the subject matter.  In this case, as the edit history shows, I am muddling about quite a bit.

I had to look up the Frobenius inequality and I understand how you get $ M \leq \text{rank}(C^* R_x^{-1} C) $ from it in the $N \ge M$ case.  I still don't see how it could be greater than $M$.

Oriol B inserted:

> Regarding your question about the Frobenius inequality, I derived it as follows:
>   $\text{rank}(C^* R_x^{-1} C) \geq \text{rank}(C^*R_x^{-1}) + \text{rank}(R_x^{-1}C) - \text{rank}(R_x^{-1})=\text{rank}(C^*R_x^{-1}) + \text{rank}(R_x^{-1}C) - M $. And by now using Sylvester's rank inequality, we get $\text{rank}(C^*R_x^{-1}C) \geq \text{rank}(C^*R_x^{-1}) + \text{rank}(R_x^{-1}C) - M \geq rank(C^*) + \text{rank}(R_x^{-1}) - M + \text{rank}(R_x^{-1}) + \text{rank}(C) - M - M = \text{rank}(C^*) + \text{rank}(C) - M = M $
>   and the last inequality follows by the assumption.

I do feel confident in my $N>M$ argument, but thanks to this addition, you can change #5 to saying the rank of $C^* R_x^{-1} C$ is $M$.  However, if $ N > M $, then the rank is still smaller than the dimension and it is still not invertible.  It should be with $N=M$.

I'm still mucking with the $N \le M$ case.  Using Frobenius you get $ \text{rank}(C^* R_x^{-1} C) \ge 2N - M $.  For $N=M$ it looks like the result will have rank N and be NxN so it will be invertible.

Since the $N<M$ case is of no interest to you I am stopping for a while on this.

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c364309h1480887_rank_inequalities_and_some_consequences

---

Another update:

I think I found the first flaw in your argument.  I mean, there has to be one in order for mine to be correct.  ;-)

$C$ is $M$x$N$ and $y$ is $N$x$1$ so $Cy$ is $M$x$1$.

$Cy$ can be interpreted as the linear combination of $N$ $M$ length vectors (the columns of C).  If $N>M$, your assertion that Cy can't be zero is false.

---

I'm not sure where your misconception arises.  Here is a concrete counter example:

Suppose $M=2,N=3$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
-1 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ Cy = 0 $$

Clearly, $y \ne 0$ yet $Cy$ is.  The rank of $C$ is 2.

---

Response to OriolB's "Of course your assumption ..." comment:

By "your assumption" you mean my second case of $N \le M$.  I didn't get that, sorry.

It seems that you have removed the "less than or" part of step 5, thus proving it invertible.  I had left it hanging since you had said you were only interested in $N>M$ which I proved was not invertible in the first case.

For the $N>M$ case, perhaps a pseudo-inverse will suffice for your greater purposes.

Comment: @OriolB Your comment is hard to decipher.  I get how you derived it, I'm just a bit puzzled about what it says.

Comment: Sorry about that @cedron, I incorporated my comment in your reply inside the yellow box since it was hard to format as a comment.

Comment: @OriolB Yeah, you did so while I was editing, so you must have missed my edit.  I have left it there, but I think it would have been better for you to append your own answer so no one is confused about authorship.  I have re-inserted my edit.

Comment: @OriolB Ponder my latest appendum.

Comment: you are absolutely right. The range being $M$ means that the null-space is $N−M$ not zero, so there are cases like yours where we obtain zero for a non-zero input. Sorry for the silly confusion, I just confused the dimensions. Check my updated answer (now with your same assumption!)